# add approve date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to add approve date from approval table i tried but it not works

sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spdocuments]
as
    SELECT    dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID,
dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate , 

  dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 

    dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
    dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
 dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status

FROM         dbo.DocumentInfo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
                      left join dbo.Approval on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID= dbo.Approval.ApproveID 
                      AND dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID= dbo.Approval.DocID
```

whereas in approval table and in this approvedate data exist

```
SeqNO   DocID   ApproveID  AppoveBy DesigID          ApproveDate
258 30  1       sundus  1         2013-12-25 18:34:47.347
259 30  1       kaneez  2        2013-12-25 18:34:47.347
260 31  1        wajihazeb  3      2013-12-26 12:17:37.150
```

it returns me like this

```
DocumentID  DocumentName    UploadedDate    FileUploaded    UploadedBy  Department  Status
30  computer science report 2013-12-25 18:31:26.420 dotnetcodes.docx    noreen  Computer Science    Pending
31  manual hr   2013-12-26 12:16:54.830 The Business Memo.doc   kulsoom Human Resource  Approve
31  manual hr   2013-12-26 12:16:54.830 The Business Memo.doc   kulsoom Human Resource  Approve
31  manual hr   2013-12-26 12:16:54.830 The Business Memo.doc   kulsoom Human Resource  Approve
```

Comment: it can not show me approve date column

Comment: Try the following: `left join dbo.Approval on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID= dbo.Approval.ApproveID AND dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID= dbo.Approval.DocID` for your last join

Comment: when i try ur query it returns me multiple records please see my update question

Comment: This means that you either have multiple records for `Resource`(3 records) in the Department table or mulitiple records for the same ApprovalType. What do you get for docID=31 when you run your initial query?

Comment: you have more than one person approve that doc in approval. is that error or intended? or you can create subquery containting only docid and join with that subquery. choose min or max approve date as you want

Comment: @kirkil when i run my initial query it show me records correctly and also not show me multiple recrods but without approvedate column and when i add last line which u suggest me then it shows me multiple records..

Answer (score 0):

last line is the culprit

```
dbo.Approval on dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.Approval.ApproveDate
```

will never give any result

Comment: obviously dbo.Approval.ApproveID cannot equal to dbo.Approval.ApproveDate right? So you might start with what is your key between Approval table and DocumentInfo table :)

Comment: approve id ...but when i write approve id it shows me multiple records